The correct dimensional formula for distance travelled in $n$th second?
I have read other similar questions on this site (including The dimensional formula of distance travelled in $n$th second with the same name), but it does not specifically answer what I was looking for.
The answer that confuses me:
My physics teacher, several answers on the internet, and the reference book I am using say that this dimensional formula should be $[LT^{-1}]$. I am not satisfied with the answer, because it seems illogical to say that the distance travelled in n-th second is not a distance but a speed since its dimensional formula is $[LT^{-1}]$.
My answer:
In my opinion, the correct answer should be $[L]$. Here is my proof:
Let us start with derivation of distance travelled in n-th seconds: (Here, $s_k$ means distance travelled in $k$ seconds)
$s_n = un+\frac{1}{2}an^2$
$s_{n-1} = u(n-1)+\frac{1}{2}a(n-1)^2$
$s_{n^{th}} = s_n - s_{n-1} = u + \frac{1}{2}a(2n-1)$
Now, the above form looks deceptive. But actually, in my opinion, it should be:
$u\cdot(1\text{second}) + \frac{1}{2}a(2n-1)\cdot(1\text{second})^2$
If we find the dimensional formula for this, it becomes $[L]$, which makes sense for a distance!
Final question
I am confused right now about whether my logic is true, due to the number of sources saying the opposite.
Which answer is correct: $[LT^{-1}]$ or $[L]$?

Your My answer part is the answer of the quoted question, how does that not solve your issue? If you say sources have disagreed it would be better to cite those sources (aside from the professors quote) as several answers on the internet doesn't help us.

Of course the dimension of the distance travelled should be $[L]$. Maybe cite the sources that state otherwise

Also how does the accepted answer not answer your question?

Your physics teacher sounds like they'd think that the average speed of the car over the past hour is $75.1\textrm{ km h}^{-1}\textrm{/h}$ rather than just $75.1\textrm{ km h}^{-1},$ and that the average production cost is $$459\text{/unit}$ rather than just $$459;$ your physics teacher is wrong.

Thanks for the confirmation (I only required the confirmation). I was talking about a website which gave the incorrect answer. But, I know they can be wrong as well. I got my answer though, thanks!
